# Haxe Type Not Found

Tags: terminal, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to run the most basic Haxe program but keep getting errors.

The `Main.hx` file looks like this:

```
package;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.Lib;
import flixel.FlxGame;
import flixel.FlxState;

class Main extends Sprite {

var gameWidth:Int = 640; // Width of the game in pixels (might be less / more in actual pixels depending on your zoom).
var gameHeight:Int = 480; // Height of the game in pixels (might be less / more in actual pixels depending on your zoom).
var initialState:Class<FlxState> = MenuState; // The FlxState the game starts with.
var zoom:Float = -1; // If -1, zoom is automatically calculated to fit the window dimensions.
var framerate:Int = 60; // How many frames per second the game should run at.
var skipSplash:Bool = false; // Whether to skip the flixel splash screen that appears in release mode.
var startFullscreen:Bool = false; // Whether to start the game in fullscreen on desktop targets

// You can pretty much ignore everything from here on - your code should go in your states.

public static function main():Void
{   
    Lib.current.addChild(new Main());
}

public function new() 
{
    super();

    if (stage != null) 
    {
        init();
    }
    else 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }
}

private function init(?E:Event):Void 
{
    if (hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE))
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    setupGame();
}

private function setupGame():Void
{
    var stageWidth:Int = Lib.current.stage.stageWidth;
    var stageHeight:Int = Lib.current.stage.stageHeight;

    if (zoom == -1)
    {
        var ratioX:Float = stageWidth / gameWidth;
        var ratioY:Float = stageHeight / gameHeight;
        zoom = Math.min(ratioX, ratioY);
        gameWidth = Math.ceil(stageWidth / zoom);
        gameHeight = Math.ceil(stageHeight / zoom);
    }

    addChild(new FlxGame(gameWidth, gameHeight, initialState, zoom, framerate, framerate, skipSplash, startFullscreen));
}
}
```

Just the generic template file. When I run it in Terminal (running Mac OS X El Capitan), I get this error:

`Main.hx:8: characters 7-21 : Type not found : flixel.FlxGame`

Haven't had problems with the installations or anything and I am new to Haxe so I don't know where to start. Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you install HaxeFlixel? When you type `haxelib list` do you see something like `flixel: 3.3.11`? What command are you using to run it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the library when you try to run your game ?

You can do that by using the command line `haxe -lib flixel -main Main ...`.

Or by writting an hxml file containing all your CLI arguments :

```
-lib flixel
-main Main
```

***Update after @Gama11 comment :***

HaxeFlixel used the OpenFL format for the compilation information (see http://www.openfl.org/documentation/projects/project-files/xml-format/).

So you should include include flixel library using : `<haxelib name="flixel" />`in your `Project.xml` file.

Comment: And of course you need to install the haxeflixel library http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/install-haxeflixel/

Comment: Flixel is built on top of OpenFL. OpenFL projects are compiled using `lime` and its [xml project files](http://www.openfl.org/documentation/projects/project-files/xml-format/), not `haxe` and `hxml`.

Comment: Oh @Gama11, I forget about this point. You are true.I will update a little my answer so.